# tshark "--export-objects" does not work, contrary to man pages

Tags: debian, wireshark, pcap, tshark

The debian manual pages define that tshark should have the functionality to export files discovered in a tcp stream with the tshark pcapname.pcap --export-objects command. If you ctrl-f the following page you will find this

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tshark/tshark.1.en.html

"export-objects ,
Export all objects within a protocol into directory destdir. The available values for protocol can be listed with --export-objects help."

However when running the latest version of tshark in debian jessie it is possible to see that this is not actually the case.

```
 tshark: unrecognized option '--export-objects'
```

Is this an expected error or have i messed up? Or is it the case that the tshark developers/package developers have neglected to include this functionality outside of the manual pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option is quite recent, so my guess would be that you have an older version of tshark.

The `--export-objects` option requires [tshark v2.4.0](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/commit/20c57cb298e4f3b7ac66a22fb7477e4cf424a11b).